# How to write a function that returns a subset of elements based on the probability % stored in the element?

Tags: php

I have the following array

```
$arr = array(
    "person1" => 10,
    "person2" => 10,
    "person3" => 20,
    "person4" => 25,
    "person5" => 35,                    
);
```

I would like to write a function that takes `$arr` as an argument and returns 3 elements of the array based on the values stored in each element.

For example if the returned subset yields

```
$newArr = array(
    "person5" => 35,  
    "person1" => 10,
    "person4" => 25,                  
);
```

There was a 35% chance that person5 would be the first element stored in `$newArr` based on the value stored in `$arr['person5']` divided by the sum of values stored in the remaining elements.
`$arr['person5']/($arr['person5'] + $arr['person4'] + $arr['person3'] + $arr['person2'] + $arr['person1'])`

There was a ~15% chance that person1 would be the second element stored in `$newArr` based on the value stored in `$arr['person1']` divided by the sum of values stored in the remaining elements.
`$arr['person1']/($arr['person4'] + $arr['person3'] + $arr['person2'] + $arr['person1'])`

There was a ~45% chance that person4 would be the second element stored in `$newArr` based on the value stored in `$arr['person4']` divided by the sum of values stored in the remaining elements.
`$arr['person4']/($arr['person4'] + $arr['person3'] + $arr['person2'])`

How could I write a function that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a roulette wheel selection algorithm, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_proportionate_selection

```
$count = 3;
$arr = array(
    "person1" => 10,
    "person2" => 10,
    "person3" => 20,
    "person4" => 25,
    "person5" => 35,                    
);

$result = array();

// sort from low to high
asort($arr);

// loop 3 times (based on count)
while ($count > 0){

    // get the sum of all persons
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $rank){
        $sum += $rank;
    }

    // get a random value between 0 and sum
    $delta = rand(0, $sum);
    $current = 0;

    // keep looping over each item, increasing rank untill $sum has surpassed delta
    // see each item as as person containing a portion of the slice. The bigger the value, the greater the change of being selected
    $current = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $name => $rank){
        $current += $rank;

        if ($delta <= $current){
            $result[$name] = $rank;
            break;
        }
    }

    unset($arr[$name]);

    $count--;
}
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't work, `echo '<pre>' . print_r($result, true) . '</pre>'` added to the end of the script causes the same thing to print each time.

Comment: I did not test the code. I would encourage you next time to explain/ask for help first before downvoting. The theory is still what you need. I'll fix the sample code now.

Comment: @LedZeppelin - See the updated code. I tested it, this works. You're welcome :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, what's the purpose of including `asort($arr)`?

Comment: You don’t need to sum up all remaining values for each iteration. Just subtract the removed value.